# Geometry Nodes: How to make a beautiful randomized GIT-tree?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been battling with this project for eternity now. Always failing.

So, I would like this to be created, but with random branching and random amount of branches. The branches should get merged to the main branch and other branches also, and yes, randomly. But the image is a good reference. Optionally there could be empty but color-coded commit labels for every point on the side.

[image]

This is the best I have so far, my friend helped a little but stopped. I managed to add the branching and coloring - but I feel like the base noding of this isn't suited for what I'm after.

Blender 4.1 Beta:

[image]

[image]